# Folding chairs/tables on Shabbat

Tags: halacha, shabbat, melacha-creative-work, contemporary-halacha, boneh-soter

Is it permissible to unfold an easily foldable folding chair or table on Shabbat? Since this is easily re folded, would it still be considered under the melacha of “Boneh” or something else? If permitted, how long can one have it set for?

In this case, no screws or tightening are involved, only folding. Sources for Halacha would be appreciated

Comment: It's a question of עשיית אהל, https://ph.yhb.org.il/01-15-05/.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refer to the [Peninei Halacha](https://www.sefaria.org/Peninei_Halakhah%2C_Shabbat.15.5.7?ven=Peninei_Halakhah,_English_ed._Yeshivat_Har_Bracha&lang=bi):

> מותר לפתוח עגלת ילדים, שולחן מתקפל, כסא מתקפל, מיטה מתקפלת ולול של תינוקות, מפני שהכל שם עשוי ומחובר מערב שבת ורק פותחים אותם בשבת (שו"ע או"ח שטו, ה).
>
> One may open a baby carriage or stroller, a folding table, a folding chair, a cot, or a playpen on Shabbat because the entire structure is already completed and connected before Shabbat. The only part that is done on Shabbat is opening it (SA 315:5).

[Shulchan Aruch](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.315.5?lang=bi) there writes:

> כסא העשוי פרקים וכשרוצים לישב עליו פותחין אותה והעור נפתח וכשמסירים אותו סוגרים אותו והעור נכפל מותר לפתחו לכתחלה
>
> A chair comprised of different sections and in order to sit on it one opens the chair, which in turn unfolds its leather, and when its use is terminated it is closed and its leather folds, is permissible to open initially.